# How to access data in a complex JSON format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In the below code, why am I not able to access to data in `detail` option of the JSON? what I would like to do is loading the `firstName` , `lastName`, and `age` into the list for each object.

```js
var data = {
  "events": [{
    "date": "one",
    "event": "",
    "info": "Copenhagen",
    "detail": [{
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "lastName": "Green",
      "age": 27
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "two",
    "event": "",
    "info": "Copenhagen",
    "detail": [{
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "lastName": "Green",
      "age": 27
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "three",
    "event": "",
    "info": "Copenhagen",
    "detail": [{
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "lastName": "Green",
      "age": 27
    }]
  }]
};
for (p = 0; p < data.events.length; p++) {
  $("p").append(data.events[p].date);
  for (i = 0; i < data.events.detail.length; i++) {
    $("ul").append('<li>'+data.events.detail[i]+'</li>');

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to put `var p = 0;` in your for loop.

Comment: @Radmation *need*, no, but it wouldn't be a bad idea. same with `i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, what you have written isn't technically "JSON", it's just a JavaScript object. However, you're on the right path. It's not exactly clear what you're asking for but I've expanded on what you have to give you something that will hopefully be helpful regardless.

```js
var data = {
    "events": [
        {
            "date": "one",
            "event": "",
            "info": "Copenhagen",
            "detail": [
                {
                    "firstName": "Sally",
                    "lastName": "Green",
                    "age": 27
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "date": "two",
            "event": "",
            "info": "Copenhagen",
            "detail": [
                {
                    "firstName": "John",
                    "lastName": "Blue",
                    "age": 22
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "date": "three",
            "event": "",
            "info": "Copenhagen",
            "detail": [
                {
                    "firstName": "Sam",
                    "lastName": "Red",
                    "age": 25
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
for (i = 0; i < data.events.length; i++) {
    $(".container").append('<p>' + data.events[i].date + '</p>');
    for (j = 0; j < data.events[i].detail.length; j++) {
        $(".container").append('<ul></ul>');
        $(".container ul:last").append('<li>' + data.events[i].detail[j].firstName + '</li>');
        $(".container ul:last").append('<li>' + data.events[i].detail[j].lastName + '</li>');
        $(".container ul:last").append('<li>' + data.events[i].detail[j].age+ '</li>');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Aender but cab you please let me know what the role of `last` in `ul:last` ?

Comment: In this case every time it loops through it adds another `<ul>`, so I'm just using a `:last` selector to make sure that the content is added to the last added list.

Answer (score 1):

In your json, events is an array. But you are trying to access data.events.detail, which should be something like data.events[p].detail

Comment: True true. Try this for your inner for loop `for (var i = 0; i < data.events[p].detail.length; i++) {
    $("ul").append('<li>'+data.events[p].detail[i]+'</li>');

  }`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that `data.events` is an array, so you must specify the index inside the header of the inner `for`

`for (i = 0; i < data.events.detail.length; i++) {`

must be

`for (i = 0; i < data.events[p].detail.length; i++) {`

and, because `data.events[].detail` is an array too, you must specify that index, too.

The following code successfully retrieves the data you need:

```js
var data = {
  "events": [{
    "date": "one",
    "event": "",
    "info": "Copenhagen",
    "detail": [{
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "lastName": "Green",
      "age": 27
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "two",
    "event": "",
    "info": "Copenhagen",
    "detail": [{
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "lastName": "Green",
      "age": 27
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "three",
    "event": "",
    "info": "Copenhagen",
    "detail": [{
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "lastName": "Green",
      "age": 27
    }]
  }]
};
for (p = 0; p < data.events.length; p++) {
  $("p").append(data.events[p].date);
  for (i = 0; i < data.events[p].detail.length; i++) {
    $("ul").append(data.events[p].detail[i].firstName + ", " + data.events[p].detail[i].lastName + ". Age: " + data.events[p].detail[i].age);

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel but this is not what I want to achieve. I need to put details of each option under them imminently. what is happening now you are separating the date and details so is not clear which detail belongs to what date!